# Memes of travel.se

Tags: discussion, fun

There are [memes common to whole Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta#) and this [one](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/880/the-memes-of-it-security) inspired me to ask here .
I therefore propose that this space be used to document the memes endemic to travel.se's culture.

One meme per answer please.

Comment: I love this question!

Comment: PS - Keep it clean guys. :)

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee by clean, toilet references are ok? ;)

Comment: That's what toilet brushes are for.

Answer (score 15):

Then we've got the sh*t question. And I'm not talking about bad questions, but the volume(?) of questions we have **about [toilets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3080/101)**. It's become a thing on here.

For a list of great and sh*t **toilet questions** click here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhygiene%5D+toilet

Comment: Like I said, I wasn't talking about bad questions, but toilet-related ones ;)

Comment: Well it's barely 3am where you are so I felt some clarity was needed.

Answer (score 13):

"**They refused my visa application for no reason at all**"

> (...and when they post the formulae, you see parking, deception,
>  forgery, etc etc etc...)

A great meme that occurs globally, not just TSE

Answer (score 12):

I'm flying from New York to New Delhi and I've got 17 iPhones in my carry-on and 37 laptops in my luggage.  They are all for my personal use.  Is it going to be OK?

Comment: For what I understand, New Delhi to New York may be even worse ;)

Answer (score 11):

Roflcopterexception's **"My friend has a question"** questions ;)

Answer (score 10):

Well of course, we have **naked urls**.  I'd never heard this before, but @hippietrail first started identifying them as a 'thing'.  Apparently https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhygiene%5D+toilet is bad, but [toilet questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhygiene%5D+toilet) is good ;)

There's more, but that's all I'm posting at 2.50am ;)

Comment: @hippietrail I copy and paste: "I'm posting at 2.50am" ;)  Fair enough, I'll move one out.

Answer (score 10):

Since this has been an actual chat event:

**Ask a [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception)-style question**

Answer (score 9):

[User](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19359/user) asking "What bizzare object can I take on a plane?" and getting massivley upvoted for it.

Comment: Shouldn’t that rather be “Can I take [bizarre object] on a plane?”?

Answer (score 7):

According to **Gayot's Law** [rep begats rep](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22589784#22589784).

Answer (score 7):

I have no savings and no job.  My distant uncle, who I never met and who has never shown any previous attempt at maintaining relationships with me or my 4 siblings, is offering to sponsor me on a 5 month visit to the UK.  The amount needed will be roughly 1/2 his annual salary. Fortunately, this amount has suddenly appeared in his bank account.  What should I put down on the form?

Answer (score 4):

How about **[pnuts the corrector](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22640917#22640917)**?

Answer (score 3):

I feel like there's a **"Lucy the spammer"** meme in here somewhere too...

Comment: Hardly a Travel.SE meme, that spammer's been around other SE sites. And not a meme because the spammer isn't going to keep that name indefinitely (in fact I haven't seen him for a few days now).

Comment: they've been back several times, with new accounts with the same name :/

Comment: I know, I've been deleting these accounts on [cs.se]. But a spammer using the same name for a week or so doesn't make a meme.

Comment: It was just a thought; was trying to get the thread going.  I'm far more in favour of the toilet memes and Rofl questions

Comment: And indeed [she's back](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/19261/101)

Answer (score 3):

What about asking once more about **transit visa in UK or Schengen from X and to Y** (typically India>Frankfurt>US), while [it has been asked way too many times](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/edit/336104).